# Get fourth to the last month?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to find out fourth to the last month with a snippet.

Considering, `september`, fourth to the last month would be `june`.

I tried to get the required month and year like this

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

current_date = datetime.now()

last_4th_month = current_date.month - 3 
year = current_date.year

if current_date.month == 3:
   last_4th_month = 12
   year = current_date.year - 1

if current_date.month == 2:
   last_4th_month = 11
   year = current_date.year - 1

if current_date.month == 1:
   last_4th_month = 10
   year = current_date.year - 1

print(last_4th_month, year)
```

Is there any efficient and better way to do this?

TYPO IN THE QUESTION:
`Get fourth to the last month in python`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

four_months = date.today() + relativedelta(months=-3)
print(four_months.strftime("%B, %Y"))
```

**Output: June, 2021**

Answer (score 1):

If 3rd party libraries can be used, `dateutil`'s `relativedelta` module offers a simple solution:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


current_date = datetime.now()
target_date = current_date - relativedelta(months=3)
print(target_date.month, target_date.year)
```

Outputs **6 2021**

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the `last_4th_month` with the standard library:

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
month = today.month - 3 if today.month - 3 > 0 else 12 - today.month
year = today.year if today.month > month else today.year - 1

last_4th_month = date(year, month, today.day)
```

```
# today = date(2021, 9, 6)
>>> last_4th_month.strftime('%B, %Y')
'June, 2021'

# today = date(2021, 2, 18)
>>> last_4th_month.strftime('%B, %Y')
'October, 2020'
```

Comment: @aristotle11. Did you have time to check answers?